# Mount volume that writes in the pod, but it doesn't writes back to the host

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Is there any possibility to mount a volume in a pod without writing back to the host? for example, I have the folder "users" in the host, I want that this folder is mounted in the pod at "/data", but the pod only write and read from the "/data".

To deploy the pods, I'm using `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`.

Comment: Can you `COPY` the files in question into the image you're running?  What is "the host" in a Kubernetes context?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the answer, after you commented, i searched a way in the documentation of the image that i'm using to auto-download the data that i need, and it have a way and it works perfectly.